# How can I use Task Async Await to read files content from multiple directories recursive?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ProcessRead().Wait();
        }

        static async Task ProcessRead()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"Directory");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string fname in fileEntries)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        count++;
                        string text = File.ReadAllText(fname);
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(count);
            });
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is working but only for the given directory in EnumerateFiles.
but I want to get all the files in all directories recursive.

For example if I put the directory of windows :

```
IEnumerable<string> fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\windows");
```

I want it to read the content of all the files in the directory windows and also all the sub directories in windows. So it will read all the files content in the given root directory and all it's sub directories recursive.

This is the code now :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ProcessRead().Wait();
        }

        static async Task ProcessRead()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fileEntries = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"Directory","", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string fname in fileEntries)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        count++;
                        string text = File.ReadAllText(fname);
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(count);
            });
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories not exist the not sure if it's because I'm using .net 4.7.2

What did I do wrong that EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories is not exist ?

Comment: [EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.recursesubdirectories?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_EnumerationOptions_RecurseSubdirectories)

Comment: @JohnWu EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories not exist the not sure if it's because I'm using .net 4.7.2 

What did I do wrong that EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories is not exist ?

Comment: @BenziAvrumi `RecurseSubdirectories` exists in .NET Core 2.1 and later, as well as in .NET Standard 2.1. The latest .NET Standard version, available for .NET Fw, is 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded method for `Directory.EnumerateFiles`:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles (string path, string searchPattern, System.IO.EnumerationOptions enumerationOptions);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netcore-3.1

Specify your EnumerationOptions as `EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories`.

Comment: EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories not exist the not sure if it's because I'm using .net 4.7.2 

What did I do wrong that EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories is not exist ?